# Asp.net concerned with gridview paging

Tags: asp.net, sql

I am  trying to paging in asp.net.
so how to code for the paging.I want group of 5 items in bunch and next page carry same group of information.

Comment: Which control you are using to display the items?

Answer (score 0):

In your grid view you can add these line which will set your page with a group of 5 items

```
<PagerSettings PageButtonCount="5"></PagerSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for pagination in Grid View.

```
protected void TeacherGrid_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
   myGrid.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
   bindDataToGrid();
}
 // add columns per your requirement and bind the grid with data source.   
<asp:gridview id="myGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
AllowPaging="True" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="myGrid_PageIndexChanging">
<Columns>
   <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
   <ItemTemplate>
   <asp:Label ID="lbName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'></asp:Label>
   </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:gridview>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `GridView` you have to give the size that you want to show the number of results in the `GridView` also in code behind you have to set your page index so whenever you go to the next 5 records, it will show the next 5 records instead of same.

Fix the `PageSize` also use a `OnPageIndexChanged` to show the unique records every time.

```
<asp:GridView ID="myGridView"  PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="myGridView_OnPageIndexChanging" >
```

in codebehind you write this code in you OnPageIndexChanging...

```
protected void myGridView_OnPageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    this.myGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    this.myGridView.DataSource = this.Session["myData"];
    this.myGridView.DataBind();
}
```